# Lista HTML com imagem no UL

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso de algo parecido com o seguinte:

```
<input type="image" src="~/Images/meu-icone.png" style="max-height: 15px;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</input>
```

isto até funciona, mas fica quebrado, pois um `input` não pode ter um `ul` dentro. A ideia é clicar na imagem e abrir a lista em baixo para ser selecionado alguma opção.

Comment: Realmente, isso não existe. Coloca o `margin` e o `padding` do `ul` com valor `0` no **CSS**. Também `list-style:none`.

Comment: A imagem realmente precisa está dentro de um UL? Ou que é esperado é que ao clicar na imagem abra um menu dropdown abaixo? Sua pergunta não está bem formulada, pois seu código contradiz o título da questão.

Comment: @felipsmartins isso ai! Ao clicar na imagem quero abrir um combobox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade, bootstrap não impõe que você use somente um elemento `button` para ativar o dropdown. Você pode verficar isso olhando os fontes CSS do Twitter Boostrap, então verá que classes `.dropdown` não está subordinada a algum elemento em específico justamente porque nem sempre pode ser um botão que ativará o dropdown menu.

Dito isso, aqui vai o código completo do que você deseja:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
         <style type="text/css">
            img#dropdownMenu1 {
                /* na verdade essa largura varia de acordo com o maiio link.
                   Defini isso apenas por estética. :)
                */
                width: 172px;
            }
         </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">            
                <div class="dropdown">
                <!-- Imagem como botão -->
                <img src="http://s4.postimg.org/5i8je2bml/avatar.png" id="dropdownMenu1" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    aria-haspopup="true" 
                    aria-expanded="true"> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end col -->
        </div>  <!-- end row -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: irei testar e já aprovo a resposta se der certo.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Já há como testar aqui mesmo no Stackoverflow, é só apertar o botão azul chamado "Executar trecho de código". Boa sorte!